# Microsoft Access - Indexing And Like/Contains Criteria

Tags: ms-access, indexing, sql-like

I apologize in advance if I'm not doing this right, I'll try to follow all the rules but this is my first post on here.

The problem I'm having seems very simple.

I have a Microsoft Access 2007 database with a table that has approximately 300,000 records.  I am attempting to query one of the fields in the table with a "Like" condition...

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Field1 LIKE "*_TEST_*"
```

However, I'm finding this query has significant performance issues, taking 4-5 minutes to run compared to a few seconds if I take that particular "Like" criteria off.  I've placed an index on [Field1] to try and alleviate the issue (and maybe I'm just a bit ignorant to the finer details of indexing) but it doesn't seem to have helped at all.

A colleague of mine informed me that these "Like" or "Contains" conditions would not see an improvement because of indexing, but did not really have any other ideas.

Could anyone please explain what it is about this "Like" criteria and indexing that don't play well together?  And is there anything I can do to make this seemingly simple query work better?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Looking up "smith" in a phone-book is easy, now try to find all names that *contain* "smith"

Comment: Haha, I guess that's an elegant way to put it. Makes sense as to why the query is seeing that performance hit.  Thank you. :)

Comment: I presume thats not the full query as if that takes 4-5 minutes something is broken,  Full-Text searches/catalogs are a way around this, but pretty sure Access does not support them.

Comment: Correct, the full query has two additional criteria but they are not "Likes" and have almost zero impact to query performance... based on testing with this "Like" criteria removed. Apologies for not being more forthcoming. Though it does take an additional 4-5 minutes by simply including the "Like".

Comment: If you have two other criteria, it means that access is checking against all three on every record in your table.  Create a query first to pull only records that meet your second two criteria, then run a second query to find which records match your like criteria. Since you are running it against less records, it should run quicker. Even though you add an additional query, you should see a performance increase.

Comment: Thank you Gene!  I'll definitely give that a try.  I'm always weary of layering queries within queries because I've been told that the queries would lose the indexing properties... but in this case, I don't think the LIKE criteria would really use it anyways. XD

Comment: If Gene's suggestions don't significantly improve the performance, I would create a temp table for Ids only and write a routine that deletes all temp records, inserts the ones that match the fast criteria, and then run the like against the table joined to the temp table.

Comment: Try using the Instr() function: `SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Instr(Field1,'_TEST_') > 0`.